# Jackson map json array of key value pairs to pojo

Tags: java, json, jackson

How can the following json be converted to pojo class using jackson.

```
{
"company": [{
    "employee": {
        "address": {
            "email": "abc@gmail.com"
        },
        "info": {
            "role": "admin",
            "name": "abc"
        }
    }
},
{
    "employee": {
        "address": {
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
        },
        "info": {
            "role": "developer",
            "name": "xyz"
        }
    }
}]
}
```

Sample Java code(it will include getters and setters)

```
public class Company{
@JsonProperty("employee")
List<Employee> employee;

}
```

Comment: There is too little information provided to help you with this. At the least you'll need to show the structure of `Employee` and you should also explain exactly what you're having issues with. Give an example of what your code looks like right now, any errors you get and what the expected result of running the code is.

Comment: What have you tried so far? and did you even try googling there are plenty online json to pojo convertor ?  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

I can help you out in this .

You have to create pojo classes equivalent to this jason right . here we go

The pojo classes equivalent to your json are as mentioned below

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee
{
    private Address address;

    private Info info;

    public Address getAddress ()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress (Address address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Info getInfo ()
    {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo (Info info)
    {
        this.info = info;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [address = "+address+", info = "+info+"]";
    }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address
{
    private String email;

    public String getEmail ()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail (String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [email = "+email+"]";
    }
}
```

**Company.java**

```
public class Company
{
    private Employee employee;

    public Employee getEmployee ()
    {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee (Employee employee)
    {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [employee = "+employee+"]";
    }
}
```

**Info.java**

```
public class Info
{
    private String name;

    private String role;

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole ()
    {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole (String role)
    {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [name = "+name+", role = "+role+"]";
    }
}
```